# concatenar listas o tuplas en python

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de unir dos listas en una, lo he logrado de esta manera, pero el resultado de esto me las agrega de forma separada como se muestra a continuación:

`('123456789', 'CON CUENTA DÉBITO', 'SOLICITANTE Y USAID')`
`('BBB', 53098570)`

y quisiera obtenerla de este modo:

`('123456789', 'CON CUENTA DÉBITO', 'SOLICITANTE Y USAID', 'BBB', 53098570)`

```
def Ad100():    
    baseAd100 = []    
    
    for row in pcorte:
        if row[4] == 1008:
            x = (row[0])
            baseAd100.append(itemgetter(0,6,9)(row))
            for row2 in val:
                if x == row2[0] and row2[17] == 1008:
                    baseAd100.append(itemgetter(0,1,6)(row2))
        
    for row in baseAd100:
        print(row)
```

Comment: ¿Que estructura tienen sus listas? podria agregrar un ejemplo de la salida que espera.

Comment: No entiendo que quieres hacer en el código, pero para concatenar listas o tuplas en python es tan simple como usar el símbolo `+`. Así: `tupla1+tupla2`

Comment: La información adicional que pusiste en el comentario de la respuesta era necesaria desde el inicio. Tu pregunta solicita concatenar listas o tuplas y es lo que te han respondido. Es por eso que se solicita un ejemplo mínimo donde se pueda reproducir el problema y un ejemplo de la salida esperada. La información adicional cambia la intención de la pregunta y por lo tanto las personas que han leído, comentado o intentado dar una respuesta han perdido su tiempo por la ambigüedad de la publicación. Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega la información completa así como un ejemplo de la salida.

Comment: No es tu primera pregunta y al revisar las anteriores has redactado buenas preguntas con la información necesaria, por favor no pierdas esa buena costumbre, eso facilita el trabajo de las personas que deseen colaborar o contribuir a resolver tu problema. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como dice en su comentario el compañero @AlfredoMaussa, solo necesitas concatenar:

```
lista1 = ('123456789', 'CON CUENTA DÉBITO', 'SOLICITANTE Y USAID')
lista2 = ('BBB', 53098570)
lista3 = lista1+lista2

lista3
```

output:

```
('123456789', 'CON CUENTA DÉBITO', 'SOLICITANTE Y USAID', 'BBB', 53098570)
```

Comment: Hola @Esei gracias por tu aporte, sin embargo no es así, ya que primero recorro una en un for y hago una validacion si es verdadera, paso a la segunda lista en el segundo for y hago otra validación y al final uno estas tuplas, pero no por compleo,  solo algunas posiciones de cada tupa con itemgetter de la primera las posiciones 0,6 y 9 y de la segunda 0,1 y 6.
El método lista1+lista2 me agrega por completo ambas tuplas y yo necesito solo una parte, lo cual ya lo hago, pero quisiera saliera de este modo ('123456789', 'CON CUENTA DÉBITO', 'SOLICITANTE Y USAID', 'BBB', 53098570)

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y añde mas detalles

Answer (score 0):

Listo, validando en el append agrege los campos que requería, quedando de este modo el código

```
for row in pcorte:
    if row[4] == 1008:
        x = (row[0])            
        for row2 in val:                
            if x == row2[0] and row2[17] == 1008:
                temp.append(itemgetter(0,6,9)(row) + itemgetter(0,1,6)(row2)) ##En este punto con itemgetter obtengo las posiciones que quiero y luego lo concateno
```

obteniendo el siguiente resultado:

```
('123456789', 'CON CUENTA DÉBITO', 'SOLICITANTE Y USAID', 'BBB', 53098570)
```